# APEX 3.2: How to send email from Outlook

Tags: oracle-apex

I am looking to have a link in my APEX page that will open an Outlook email with a specific subject and to.  Can anyone point me in the direction of an example of this or provide a quick high level of how to do this?

```
TO: Email_Name@email.com
Subject: Specific Text Here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

1. Create a new list entry.
2. Set the target type to: URL
3. Set the URL Target to: mailto:Someone@Somewhere.com?cc=SomeOneElse@Someplace.com&subject=Enormous Teeth